# long duration in calling SOAP web service using Java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soapui

I'm testing SOAP web service first time with Java program and second time using SOAP-UI program.
Java Program method call last about 500ms but when i use SOAP-UI duration is about 20ms.
Part of Java code calculating time duration is:

```
Date st = new Date();
OutStructure out = wsStmtMessageSetPortType.method(inputStructure);
long duration = (new Date().getTime() - st.getTime());
```

I also checked time in Wireshark in both method duration between request and response is about 20ms.
why in Java code my program duration is about 500ms?
as the code shows 500ms is just the time of method call not any other calculation.

Comment: Depends on the client your Java code is using. Your client might not be as efficient as SoapUI have.

Comment: Just because you happened to run Wireshark to look at your data, that doesn't make this a Wireshark question.  :)

Comment: SOAP-UI is written in Java, so basically something is wrong with your client (or the request).

Comment: This sounds just like the other recently logged issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49104627/lengthy-soapui-method-call.  I've put some general comments against that issue that might be worth looking at.