# lengthy SOAPUI method call

Tags: soap, soapui

I have noticed a problem about webservice execution duration in my client app (java ws-Jax).
I noticed method call duration is about 500ms.
Then I setup SOAPUI application to test method call.
By repeating SOAPUI execution, 20% of run has ~35ms but remain 80% has ~500ms duration!!
I ran a wire shark and found response packet always received in ~30ms.
I can't find why SOAPUI processed it for long time.
If it need to send wsdl or request & response xml, I can attach them later.
Looking for any advise
Thanks

Comment: On the face of it, it seems from your Q that SoapUI is (for 80% of the calls) consistent with your client app, so I'm not sure SoapUI is to blame here.  As for the 30-35ms calls, are you sure that the service is actually returning the expected value in those calls?  SoapUI lets you create assertions base on status (200, 500) and content in the response.  My approach here would be to verify the response in terms of status and content.  I'd then run the call many times and if the 35ms response is valid, then I'd be asking who wrote the service to check the performance of their system.

Comment: As for WireShark, isn't that just a packet sniffer?  I've never used it, but from their site, it doesn't look like it tests web services, though I could be wrong.  For example, just because it can ping the host in 35ms, that doesn't mean your web service call should take 35ms to respond as you don't always know how much work is required to build the response you've asked for.